# The project system has encountered an error When trying to load project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

In Visual Studio 2017 v15.7.1 I am getting the following error window when trying to load one of my projects:

[image: VS error window]

And when I go to the path specified, inside the test file I find a very long stack-trace which I could not copy all of it because it exceeds allowed characters count.

> ===================== 5/31/2018 3:40:57 PM LimitedFunctionality System.AggregateException: Project system data flow
>   'ProjectBuildSnapshotService Outer 320459' closed because of an
>   exception: System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred.
>   ---> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. --->
>   System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. --->
>   System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance
>   of an object.    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectServices.DesignTimeBuilder.d__17.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.Build.DesignTimeBuilderService.BuilderLifetimeHelper.d__12.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.Build.DesignTimeBuilderService.d__36.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.Build.DesignTimeBuilderService.d__36.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
>   at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.Build.DesignTimeBuildManagerService.d__55.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
>   at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.Build.DesignTimeBuildManagerService.d__53.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.Designers.ProjectBuildSnapshotService.d__74.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
>   at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.Designers.ProjectBuildSnapshotService.<>c__DisplayClass72_0.<b__0>d.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading.JoinableTask.d__78.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading.JoinableTask`1.<JoinAsync>d__3.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.Designers.ProjectBuildSnapshotService.<UpdateSnapshotCoreAsync>d__72.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
>
>   at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.Designers.CustomizableBlockSubscriberBase`3.d__34.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.Designers.CustomizableBlockSubscriberBase`3.<>c__DisplayClass32_0.<<Initialize>b__1>d.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading.JoinableTask.<JoinAsync>d__78.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.Designers.CustomizableBlockSubscriberBase`3.<b__32_0>d.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.DataflowExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass24_0`2.<b__0>d.MoveNext()

Comment: Did you move the project. Example I got this error on all my apps that I made in VS Community 2015 and changed to VS Community 2017. I think it has to do with framework and the location. Looking at the stack trace file from what I see is parts of the app has been moved. May be a VS bug.

Comment: I just checked apps that I made in VS Enterprise and opened them in VS Community 2017, the same thing happened to me.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I found that you need to do two steps to resolve this issue:

1. Delete the `.vs` folder at the solution level.
2. Delete the `bin` and `obj` folders in all projects within the solution.

---

I encountered the issue in Visual Studio 2017 v15.7.4 and the affected project/solution was created in v15.7.4, so it can occur without upgrading to a new version of Visual Studio.

Comment: Deleting the `.vs` folder resolved this issue for me.  No need to delete `bin` and `obj` folders.

Comment: Same here. Deleting the `.vs` folder resolved this issue for me.

Comment: Deleting only the `.vs` folder did not help. I had to delete the `bin` and `obj` folders as well. Visual Studio 2017 Version 15.7.1 - I see this problem on F# projects, never on C#.

Answer (score 2):

Try deleting bin and obj folders in all projects of that solution. 
Probably those folders were having old files generated by some older version of visual studio, which are not compatible with new version of visual studio.

Comment: Deleting bin folders fixed the issue, which happened when I reverted to an old commit using visual studio

Answer (score 0):

I want to share a shell script that recursively removes `bin` and `obj` directories from the current directory

Navigate to the root directory of your solution via `git bash` or `wsl`

Run

```sh
find . -type d \( -name bin -o -name obj \) -exec rm -r "{}" \;
```

Enjoy!