# Visual Studio 2019 fails to load a project

Tags: visual-studio, .net-core

My project is open source and [sits on GitHub](https://github.com/JwanKhalaf/Bejebeje.Api/tree/feature/auth-logic-when-getting-artists). I turned on my computer to do some work, but all of a sudden Visual Studio Enterprise 2019 (v 16.2.5) tells me it can't load my `.Api` project.

I haven't made changes to the `.csproj` file. The error I'm getting is this:

[image: visual studio fails to load project]

The text in the log is:

```
=====================
17/09/2019 11:50:30
Recoverable
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.CompositionFailedException: An exception was thrown while initializing part "Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Razor.ProjectSystem.FallbackRazorProjectHost". ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
    at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Razor.FilePathComparer.get_Instance()
    at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Razor.ProjectSystem.RazorProjectHostBase..ctor(IUnconfiguredProjectCommonServices commonServices, Workspace workspace)
    at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Razor.ProjectSystem.FallbackRazorProjectHost..ctor(IUnconfiguredProjectCommonServices commonServices, Workspace workspace)
    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.RuntimeExportProviderFactory.RuntimeExportProvider.RuntimePartLifecycleTracker.CreateValue()
    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.ExportProvider.PartLifecycleTracker.Create()
    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.ExportProvider.PartLifecycleTracker.MoveNext(PartLifecycleState nextState)
    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.ExportProvider.PartLifecycleTracker.MoveToState(PartLifecycleState requiredState)
    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.ExportProvider.PartLifecycleTracker.GetValueReadyToExpose()
    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.RuntimeExportProviderFactory.RuntimeExportProvider.<>c__DisplayClass15_0.<GetExportedValueHelper>b__0()
    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.DelegateServices.<>c__DisplayClass2_0`1.<As>b__0()
    at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
    at System.Lazy`1.LazyInitValue()
    at System.Lazy`1.get_Value()
    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.MefExtensions.<ExtensionValues>d__12`1.MoveNext()
    at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
    at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.UnconfiguredProjectImpl.Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.IProjectCapabilitiesScopeContext.EvaluateAutoLoadComponentsHandlingCapabilitiesChanges()
    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.ProjectCapabilitiesScope.<PrepareNewCapabilitiesSnapshotAsync>d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.ProjectCapabilitiesScopeBase.<ProcessNewCapabilitiesAsync>d__47.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading.JoinableTask.<JoinAsync>d__68.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading.JoinableTask`1.<JoinAsync>d__3.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.ProjectCapabilitiesScopeBase.<<Initialize>b__41_0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.TransformBlockSlim`2.TransformBlockSlimAsync.<ProcessInputAsync>d__3.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.DataReceivingBlockSlim`1.<ProcessInputQueueAsync>d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.ProjectDataSources.<GetLatestVersionAsync>d__30`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.UnconfiguredProjectImpl.<LoadConfiguredProjectAsync>d__166.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.UnconfiguredProjectImpl.<GetSuggestedConfiguredProjectAsync>d__179.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.Configuration.BaseProjectConfigurationDimensionProvider.<GetPropertyValue>d__19.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.Configuration.BaseProjectConfigurationDimensionProvider.<GetOrderedPropertyValuesAsync>d__13.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.Configuration.BaseProjectConfigurationDimensionProvider.<GetDefaultValuesForDimensionsAsync>d__14.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.DefaultingProjectConfigurationsServiceBase.<AddDefaultValuesForMissingDimensionsAsync>d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.DefaultingProjectConfigurationsServiceBase.<ConvertMinimalConfigurationToProjectConfigurationAsync>d__4.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.Implementation.Package.ProjectFactory.BackgroundLoad.<LoadAndSetInitialProjectConfigurationAsync>d__40.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.Implementation.Package.ProjectFactory.BackgroundLoad.<LoadInitialConfigurationAsync>d__36.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.Implementation.Package.ProjectFactory.BackgroundLoad.Step.<<Initialize>b__14_0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading.JoinableTask.<JoinAsync>d__68.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.Implementation.Package.ProjectFactory.BackgroundLoad.Step.<StepAsync>d__12.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.Implementation.Package.ProjectFactory.BackgroundLoad.<RunStepsAsync>d__30.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.DataReceivingBlockSlim`1.<ProcessInputQueueAsync>d__5.MoveNext()
    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
---> (Inner Exception #0) Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.CompositionFailedException: An exception was thrown while initializing part "Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Razor.ProjectSystem.FallbackRazorProjectHost". ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
    at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Razor.FilePathComparer.get_Instance()
    at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Razor.ProjectSystem.RazorProjectHostBase..ctor(IUnconfiguredProjectCommonServices commonServices, Workspace workspace)
    at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Razor.ProjectSystem.FallbackRazorProjectHost..ctor(IUnconfiguredProjectCommonServices commonServices, Workspace workspace)
    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.RuntimeExportProviderFactory.RuntimeExportProvider.RuntimePartLifecycleTracker.CreateValue()
    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.ExportProvider.PartLifecycleTracker.Create()
    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.ExportProvider.PartLifecycleTracker.MoveNext(PartLifecycleState nextState)
    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.ExportProvider.PartLifecycleTracker.MoveToState(PartLifecycleState requiredState)
    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.ExportProvider.PartLifecycleTracker.GetValueReadyToExpose()
    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.RuntimeExportProviderFactory.RuntimeExportProvider.<>c__DisplayClass15_0.<GetExportedValueHelper>b__0()
    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.DelegateServices.<>c__DisplayClass2_0`1.<As>b__0()
    at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
    at System.Lazy`1.LazyInitValue()
    at System.Lazy`1.get_Value()
    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.MefExtensions.<ExtensionValues>d__12`1.MoveNext()
    at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
    at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.UnconfiguredProjectImpl.Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.IProjectCapabilitiesScopeContext.EvaluateAutoLoadComponentsHandlingCapabilitiesChanges()
    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.ProjectCapabilitiesScope.<PrepareNewCapabilitiesSnapshotAsync>d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.ProjectCapabilitiesScopeBase.<ProcessNewCapabilitiesAsync>d__47.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading.JoinableTask.<JoinAsync>d__68.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading.JoinableTask`1.<JoinAsync>d__3.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.ProjectCapabilitiesScopeBase.<<Initialize>b__41_0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.TransformBlockSlim`2.TransformBlockSlimAsync.<ProcessInputAsync>d__3.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.DataReceivingBlockSlim`1.<ProcessInputQueueAsync>d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.ProjectDataSources.<GetLatestVersionAsync>d__30`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.UnconfiguredProjectImpl.<LoadConfiguredProjectAsync>d__166.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.UnconfiguredProjectImpl.<GetSuggestedConfiguredProjectAsync>d__179.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.Configuration.BaseProjectConfigurationDimensionProvider.<GetPropertyValue>d__19.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.Configuration.BaseProjectConfigurationDimensionProvider.<GetOrderedPropertyValuesAsync>d__13.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.Configuration.BaseProjectConfigurationDimensionProvider.<GetDefaultValuesForDimensionsAsync>d__14.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.DefaultingProjectConfigurationsServiceBase.<AddDefaultValuesForMissingDimensionsAsync>d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.DefaultingProjectConfigurationsServiceBase.<ConvertMinimalConfigurationToProjectConfigurationAsync>d__4.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.Implementation.Package.ProjectFactory.BackgroundLoad.<LoadAndSetInitialProjectConfigurationAsync>d__40.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.Implementation.Package.ProjectFactory.BackgroundLoad.<LoadInitialConfigurationAsync>d__36.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.Implementation.Package.ProjectFactory.BackgroundLoad.Step.<<Initialize>b__14_0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading.JoinableTask.<JoinAsync>d__68.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.Implementation.Package.ProjectFactory.BackgroundLoad.Step.<StepAsync>d__12.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.Implementation.Package.ProjectFactory.BackgroundLoad.<RunStepsAsync>d__30.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.DataReceivingBlockSlim`1.<ProcessInputQueueAsync>d__5.MoveNext()<---

===================
```

I found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50624775/the-project-system-has-encountered-an-error-when-trying-to-load-project) and tried the suggestion of closing Visual Studio, removing all the `bin` and `obj` folders from all projects as well as removing the `.vs` folder from the root, then opening up Visual Studio and trying again, but sadly it didn't work. I got the same error.

What is even stranger is that the solution builds fine via command line.

[image: building solution through command line]

What am I missing?

Comment: Good point, I'll add it.